# Java remove listener, when callback is executed

Tags: java, events

I just can't figure out how to remove listener when I have some event executed. I have some leaking issue using websockets, and this can probaly fix it.

```
final WebSocket w = asyncHttpClient.prepareGet(url)
    .execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder().build())
    .get();

w.addWebSocketListener(new WebSocketTextListener() {

    public void onMessage(String message) {
        listener.onMessage(responseMessage);
        // Here is the place I want to do my w.removeWebSocketListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragment(String s, boolean b) {
    }

    public void onOpen(WebSocket websocket) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket webSocket) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
    }

});
```

The problem is when I create `WebSocketTextListener lis = new ....` and passing in there is something like one object need other object and other object is dependent on this, and I'm still now allowed to do what I want.
Looks like it is something simple, but can't figure out.

Comment: what exactly happens when you uncomment your line?

Comment: right now this is non workable, because I don't have name of listener.  If I change code to WebSocketTextListener lis = new WebSocketTextListener() {....w.removeWebSocketListener(lis); } eclipse say I need to have final WebSocketTextListener lis =...  and now it complains that  listener can be not instantiated, but now I'm now allowed to add line WebSocketTextListener lis = null   before. because it is final

Comment: You are still not making a lot of sense. `final WebSocketTextListener lis = new WebSocketTextListener() {....w.removeWebSocketListener(lis); }` should work, why doesnt' it?

Comment: because I can pass only final object to noname class, but if I do this, eclipse complains that there is possibility that listener would not be instantiated (forcing me do do WebSocketTextListener lis = null;  before actually making lis = new ...  but if I assing to null I can't anymore change reference, because it is final. What is the best way to refactor this, have ideas?

Comment: But you **are** passing a final object to the noname class, which is the instance of that same noname class. You are passing `lis` into `lis`, and `lis` is final. Therefore I don't see what is tripping you up. OK, I think I get it now: `lis` is within scope, but Java won't let you use it because it may not have been assigned at that point. Then I guess the only option is to use `this`, as your answerer explains.

Comment: Yes, you explained, better than me, what problem I have) I'm trying with THIS reference right now, but I am not sure will THIS be the reference to lis, or reference to object from where I'm making all work. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: You don't have to worry about it because a simple test will prove it. `this` indeed refers to the anonymous class instance. Example: `new Runnable() { public void run() { System.out.println(this.getClass()); }}` is a proof.

Comment: Yes, I saw in debugger that listener was removed, that's great! because I was worring about collecting list of listeners, adding aditional methods for doing somethig simmilar and having no guarantee of working, but this helped. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Normally event listeners can be removed with a `removeXXXListener` method. But it requires that you provide the *exact* same event listener instance as parameter. You can store the event listener and later remove it using the same reference. But since you, in the `onMessage` message already are inside the scope of the event listener, using `this` should work.

Try something like

```
listener.onMessage(responseMessage);
// Here is the place I want to do my w.removeWebSocketListener(l);
w.removeWebSocketListener(this);
```

Comment: "this" in this case is reference to noname listener? Will try it

Comment: Thanks it actually removed listener

Comment: Yep - since you are defining a ``new WebSocketTextListener`` all the code inside the (anonymous) class will use ``this`` as a referral to the listener itself. When the ``}`` end the class, ``this`` will no longer point to the listener, but to something else (in this case the class in which you define ``w``. Just FYI :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using "this" in anonumous inner class is the way to solve problem. But, it is muck better to refactor code, to avoid using anonumous classes, for testability and better understanding.